# Fortran get complex number from a real number.

Tags: fortran

I am working on writing a Fortran which has to solve square root and that results in getting a complex number, but Fortran doesn't print it or passes that to another variable. It gives (NaN, 0.000).

This is a dummy code to represent the problem that i am having with the actual code i am working on. If you guys can give me any information that would be helpful. Thank You.

```
   program test
       IMPLICIT NONE
       COMPLEX X
       REAL a, b, c
       a = 1
       b = 1
       c = 1
       X = sqrt(b - 4*a*c)
       print *, REAL(X), ' - j',-AIMAG(X)
   end program test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a, b and c are all reals, the expression on the right-hand side of the assignment will be calculated in real arithmetic.  Assigning it to a complex variable on the left-hand side doesn't change that.  If you want the calculation done as a complex value, the easiest way is to declare a, b, and c as complex.